# Drupal views ui won't edit or update options

Tags: php, jquery, drupal, view

My views ui, in production, has stopped showing the second popup for all options. A few hours of googling has led me to disable the js and try adding/changing fields or settings, but I still never get the configure field screen.

Instead when I select a field from the add screen/popup I keep going back to the main view edit page for this display.

My view module in sites/all hasn't been changed since June '14, my jquery is still 1.4 (with no change module) and I don't have this issue on my staging site (which mirrors my production site when views are concerned).  My error log and all the reports within drupal are unrelated or clear.

Any suggestions or things I could try to get views to behave?